# Integrating $\int x\frac{\operatorname{Ai}'(x+a)}{\operatorname{Ai}(x+a)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, airy-functions

Is it possible to evaluate the integral

$$\int\frac{\operatorname{Ai}'(x+a)}{\operatorname{Ai}(x+a)}xdx$$

where $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ is an Airy function, and $a$ is a constant, in terms of special functions?

Edit: since it was pointed out that since $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ will have zeros that make this poorly defined, can we instead find a closed form for an integral of the form

$$\int_c^x\frac{\operatorname{Ai}'(t-a)}{\operatorname{Ai}(t-a)}tdt,$$
where $c>a$, so that we avoid these singularities?

Comment: It is in my interest because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The Airy function has tons of zeros (on the negative axis) which will lead to non.-integrable singularities in the integrand. So your function is not even defined for negative enough $a$. I would say "no".